# How to take "limits" of operators?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Fix $h\ne0\in\mathbb{R}$. Define $\Delta_h\in\text{End}(\mathbb{R})$ by writing $\Delta_h(f):=f((-)+h)$ for all $f\in\text{Hom}_\text{Set}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Denote identity element of $\text{End}(\mathbb{R})$ by $I$. Then, for all functions $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, we have
$$(\Delta_h+I)(f)=f((-)+h).$$
Clearly $(\Delta_h+I)^k(f)=f((-)+kh)=\Delta_{kh}(f)$, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $\text{End}(\mathbb{R})$ is a ring, the binomial formula holds and so
$$\Delta_h^n=(\Delta_h+I-I)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-I)^{n-k}(\Delta_h+I)^k.$$
It follows that, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $f\in\text{Hom}_\text{Set}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, the identity
$$\Delta^n_h(f)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\Delta_{kh}(f),$$
holds. Now suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $n$-times differentiable. I want to make sense of the limit
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta_h^n(f)}{h^n};$$
in fact, I want to somehow show that an appropriate notion of a limit exists where the above is equal to $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f$. Is such a thing possible? Where might I find the required definitions, properties, constructions, etc.? I know nothing beyond first year analysis, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is Delta_hf(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)?

Comment: @yaoliding Correct

Comment: You should fix that definition then.

Comment: @CameronWilliams What is there to fix? It's clear enough that $\Delta_h(f)(x)=f(x+h)$ for all $x$; the notation $f((-)+h)(x)$ is supposed to suggest $f(x+h)$. Mason had no trouble figuring it out, for example. And yaoliding figured it out too. So I think it's fine as is.

Comment: Doesn't mean you shouldn't fix something wrong. $\Delta_h f(x) =f(x+h) - f(x)$, but that isn't what you wrote in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume $f \in C^{m}(\mathbb{R})$. The first kind of convergence to investigate is pointwise convergence. Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that by the mean value theorem, for any $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, $(\frac{\Delta_h}{h}g)(x) = g'(x + \theta(h)h)$ for some $\theta(h) \in (0, 1)$. Also note that by linearity of differentiation, $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{\Delta_h}{h}$ commute, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\Delta_h}{h} = \frac{\Delta_h}{h}\frac{d}{dx}$. By the mean value theorem,
\begin{align}
g_h(x) &:= (\frac{\Delta_h^m}{h^m}f)(x) \\
&= (\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\Delta_h^{m - 1}}{h^{m - 1}}f)(x + \theta_1(h)h) \\
&= (\frac{\Delta_h^{m - 1}}{h^{m - 1}}\frac{d}{dx}f)(x + \theta_1(h)h) \\
&= (\frac{\Delta_h^{m - 1}}{h^{m - 1}}f')(x + \theta_1(h)h),
\end{align}
where $\theta_1(h) \in (0, 1)$. Iterating this gives
\begin{align}
 g_h(x) &= (\frac{\Delta_h^{m - 1}}{h^{m - 1}}f')(x + \theta_1(h)h) \\
 &= (\frac{\Delta_h^{m - 2}}{h^{m - 2}}f'')(x + \theta_1(h)h + \theta_2(h)h) \\
&= \dots \\
&= f^{(m)}(x + \theta_1(h)h + \dots + \theta_m(h)h).
\end{align}

Note that $|\theta_1(h)h + \dots + \theta_m(h)h| \leq m|h| \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. Since $f^{(m)}$ is continuous at $x$, it follows that $g_h(x) \to f^{(m)}(x)$ as $h \to 0$. This kind of analysis is a basis for a proof of commutativity of mixed partial derivatives.

A stronger kind of convergence to investigate is whether $g_h \to f^{(m)}$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as $h \to 0$. This is true. To prove this, it suffices to prove uniform convergence on every closed ball $\overline{B_R(0)}$ centered at $0$. To prove it, adapt the analysis for the pointwise case, and use the fact that a continuous function on a compact set it uniformly continuous, i.e. has a modulus of continuity. By induction, it follows that if $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, then for every $k \geq 0$, $g^{(k)}_h \to f^{(m + k)}$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your first method, is there a reason you extract $n$ $\theta$s? For example, for $n=3$, you can simply take $f'''(x+3h\alpha_h)$ for $\alpha_h\in(0,1)$. Then as $h\rightarrow 0$ we get $f'''(x)$. Is there benefit to using $f'''(x+\theta_1(h)h+\theta_2(2)h+\theta_3(h)h)$ instead of what I've proposed?

Comment: It's not clear how you choose your $\theta_i$s. For example, in the case of $n=2$, we have $\frac{\Delta_h^2}{h^2}f(x)=\frac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)}{h^2}$. We apply MVT twice to get $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(c_1)$ and $\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x+h)}{h}=f'(c_2)$ for some $c_1\in(x,x+h)$ and $c_2\in(x+h,x+2h)$. A third application of MVT gives $\frac{f'(c_2)-f'(c_1)}{h}=f''(c_3)$ for some $c_3\in(c_1,c_2)$. Now how do you propose to find a $\theta_1,\theta_2\in(0,1)$ such that $c_3=x+\theta_1h+\theta_2h$?

Comment: @snov The $\theta_i$s are from the $m$ applications of the mean value theorem. It seems like you put $\alpha_h = (\theta_1 + \dots + \theta_m)/m$, which is fine.

Comment: Can you please respond to my 2nd comment? I would really appreciate it. That's the only detail I have trouble working out.

Comment: @snov I see. You are right. I need to check my usage of the mean value theorem. I'll fix the post.

Comment: alright thank you

Comment: @snov Luckily my result is correct. You use the commutativity of $\frac{d}{dx}$ with $\frac{\Delta_h}{h}$.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can understand it